# How to stop printing a source code from twig files in the browser

Tags: timber

I use Timber for WordPress.

Currently I'm able to see my all source code from twig files in the browser.

Example:
`localhost:8000/wp-content/themes/name-of-theme/views/base.twig`

when hitting this url I can see code from `base.twig` file.

How to stop rendering twig files in the browser or redirect them from /views/*.twig completely? Is it possible with Timber or need special configuration with .htaccess globally? I would like to configure it inside my theme - which folders and files can be viewed by the browser. I think it's not secure because anyone can see logic from my twig files if has its name.

Comment: Place your templates in a non-public folder?

Comment: @DarkBee how to make a non-public folder in my theme's directory?

Comment: what type of server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Yes, Apache. I'm wondering how to do it without .htaccess and changing server permissions for directory. Because I would like to run my theme on some servers/projects and need to control it with WordPress code or PHP.

Comment: Going to be hard to do this with `PHP` though, easiest would indeed be with a `.htaccess` and add the `order deny,allow deny from all` lines. Even if you would want to do it with `php` you would need a rewrite rule in order to prevent direct access to the files

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file add the following

```
<Files *.twig>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```